# JQuery does not allow to load documents using a relative path

Tags: jquery, html, include

I'm using JQuery to include an HTML document into another. The hard drive that stores the HTML pages is mounted on different machines and therefore **the absolute path cannot be used** (the path changes from one machine to another).

the directory structure is:

> project/dir1/toinclude1.html
> project/dir2/toinclude2.html
> project/dir3/toinclude3.html
> project/dir4/**integration.html**

The integration.html page includes all other 3.

The problem is that the load function does NOT work with

> "../dir1/toinclude1.html" (ie., with ../)

If I move integration.html to:

> project/integration.html

It works with

> "./dir1/toinclude1.html"

But that is not optimal for me.

That looks rather strange - is that a bug?

Comment: ./ will pull you all the way out to the root.  So that kinda makes sense.

Comment: No, `./` will reference the current directory. `/` references the root.
@yocoim are you able to reference the file(s) with just `toinclude1.html` rather than `./toinclude1.html`?

Comment: without "./" works as well.